# Why does this C array reference look incorrect?

Tags: c

Below is a piece of code copied from a [website](http://www.steike.com/code/useless/evil-c/).
The value set for the direction prints the respective character from "nsew". For example the output of this code is character w.

I am wondering how does it work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main (void){
   int direction = 3;
   char direction_name = direction["nsew"];
   printf("%c",direction_name);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because the array subscript operator is commutative, i.e., this:

```
const char *p = "Hello";
char x = p[0];
```

Is equivalent to

```
const char *p = "Hello";
char x = 0[p];
```

Weird, huh?  In your case you are indexing into the third position of the string literal (which is an array) `"nsew"`.

`some_ptr[n]` is equivalent to `*(some_ptr + n)`, and since addition is commutative, it is also equivalent to `*(n + some_ptr)`. It then follows that `n[some_ptr]` is also an equivalent expression.

I wouldn't recommend using this "feature" however... seriously, don't do it.

Comment: Or: `p[0]` is the same as `*(p + 0)`, and `+` is associative.

Comment: Brian's comment bears repeating: don't do this.

Comment: It all depends on the actual layout of the data in memory. Add one variable in between, and the indexing is broken (well "changed").

Comment: @peterph: I'm not sure what you mean by that, there is no way to "break" this as long as the pointer dereference is valid (in which case you are invoking UB, so *nothing* can be considered valid any longer)

Comment: @EdS. I had the impression, that the layout of the variables in memory could change it somehow, but obviously it can't (and I should go to bed). :)

Comment: Wow, that is just horrendously awesome. Is there a case where using this makes sense?

Comment: By "associative" did you mean "commutative"?

Comment: @JuanMendes: outside of the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org), no.  You *should* never see this in production code.

Answer (score 8):

Operator `[]` has the same semantics as pointer arithmetics. So `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)` which is equivalent to `*(i + a)` which is equivalent to `i[a]`:

So `direction["nsew"]` == `"nsew"[direction]` == `"nsew"[3]` == `'w'`

Comment: +1 I like this explanation, at least there's a method to the madness